# switch function to change page based on user input not working

Tags: php, html

I am trying to change page based on user input in form. The user enters their tag and it changes to that users page with details. Currently, it just keeps attempting to change page then eventually times out. Here is my code:

SWITCH STATEMENT

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $name = $_GET['clan_tag'];

  switch($name) {

  case "player1":
    header("Location: commander.php");
    break;

  case "player2":
    header("Location: officer.php");
    break;

  ...//

  default:
    header("Location: index.php");
  }
}
```

FORM

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <input name="clan_tag" type="text" class="box" placeholder="Enter the clan players tag" autofocus />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

So if user enters `player 1` in form then submits, it should change to commander.php page, but it isn't.

Could anyone point me in correct direction thanks.

Comment: How would POST be set in a GET? `if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {`

Comment: You can only pass a POST or a GET, not both. Can you post a print_r() of your POST object. If your form is properly defined, you should be able to find what you are looking for inside the POST object.

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas technically speaking you can attach GET variables to the `action` within a POST form.

Comment: also, you might want to put an `exit;` or `die;` after your redirects, so that it doesn't run the rest of the code.

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas _"You can only pass a POST or a GET, not both"_ - not quite true. If you have a form with method POST and an action "action.php?type=test", type will be in $_GET.

Comment: Your `$_POST` is probably just not being set, so your function basically does nothing. meaning that you you are basically just refreshing the page when you submit.

Comment: Your code is `case "player1"`, but your input is `player 1` (has 1 space). It may be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, change first line to

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
```

2nd give a 'name' attribute to submit button

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="submit"/>
```

Comment: you can also use -- if ( $_GET['submit'] ){ not need to use isset()

Comment: You do need to use `isset` otherwise a warning will be thrown if the value is not set.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at your code and realized your form was sending data using the `HTTP GET` method but your PHP script was checking for `HTTP POST` method in the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`. So I modified the PHP as shown below.

```
if(isset($_GET['clan_tag'])){
    $name = $_GET['clan_tag'];
    switch($name) {
    case "player1":
      header("Location: commander.php");
      break;

    case "player2":
      header("Location: officer.php");
      break;

    default:
      header("Location: index.php");
    }
  }
?>
```

I also modified the HTML as shown below.

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <input name="clan_tag" type="text" class="box" placeholder="Enter the clan players tag" autofocus />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

Comment: I already commented that under the question 30 minutes ago. Please read all comments and other answers before answering

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

In the FORM:
attribute method write "post"  in action= write "path where is your php file"

i.e.

```
<form action="path/yourfile.php" method="post">
  <input name="clan_tag" type="text" class="box" placeholder="Enter the clan players tag" autofocus />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

in PHP file

```
if(isset($_POST['clan_tag'])) {
  $name = $_POST['clan_tag'];
}
else{
   $name="";//your code
}
```

....